# Task failures occur in mapreduce process

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I am a very new user in hadoop mapreduce. I want to test with mapreduce task failure. Could anyone give me link of sample code of 'testing mapreduce task failure'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that you want a program in Java, take any MapReduce sample working program from any tutorial website.
In the `Mapper` code, just write a line

```
throw new RuntimeException("My test exception");
```

Similarly you may test a `Reducer` code.